# TypeError Don't know how to convert parameter 2 (mouse movement)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm building a drawing tool with Python. App works without size but when I use size it does not work. I need to make bigger squares and I need to multiply all values on the lists as you can see. Looks like everything is OK but code does not work and I'm getting this error:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2
```

```
import win32api
import time
import ctypes
import mouse

sqx = [10,0,-10,0]
sqy = [0,10,0,-10]
size = 0.5

def mover(x,y):
    ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(0x0001,x,y,0,0)

while True:
for i in range(len(sqx)):
    if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x01) < 0:
        newsqx = sqx[i] * size
        newsqy = sqy[i] * size
        mover(newsqx,newsqy)
```

Here is the terminal output:

[image: Terminal output]

Comment: it looks you pass float, and maybe but I'm not sure the function expects an int?

Comment: Please paste the actual code/output instead of screenshots.

Comment: THIS IS ALREADY ACTUAL CODE. AND THERE IS 2 SCREENSHOTS.

Comment: Press the Caps Lock key to go back to regular typing.  Then copy and paste the text from the window -- you can do that by clicking and dragging so that it's highlighted, and then press Ctrl-C to copy the text and Ctrl-V to paste it into the question on SO.  That way other people can also copy and paste it into their own environments to help you debug it.  It's harder to work with screenshots of text because you can't easily paste those into an IDE or a Google search.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. All it does is making answering harder for us. Also, visually impaired people might not be able to see it and images might be blocked.

Comment: I have already posted the code.

Comment: @BeatByVenom Remove the unneeded screenshot then. People who can't see it won't know it's the same.

Comment: The terminal output should also be copied and pasted as text.

Comment: Define the functions `.argtypes` and `.restype` attributes and ctypes won't have to guess the required argument types.

Answer (score 2):

According to the win32 documentation it looks like the parameters to `mouse_event` are supposed to be integers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event

Your original `sqx` and `sqy` values are integers, but by multiplying them by a `float` you're turning them into `float`s, so that might be the source of the error.  I might suggest having the `mover` function convert `x` and `y` to `int`s so that it can accept either `float` or `int` from the caller:

```
def mover(x, y):
    ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(0x0001, int(x), int(y), 0, 0)
```